# How to make nested table match width of parent with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a nested table in html:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="altRow">
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Col 1 50%</td>
                            <td>Col 2 50%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Col 1 50%</td>
                            <td>Col 2 50%</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

with some basic CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

td {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.altRow table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

What I want is for the nested table to be the same width as the parent table with two columns, each 50% of the parent.

For example, if the parent table spans 100% of the page width I would expect the row with the class "altRow" to also span the whole page width along with all it's decendents. The altrow bottom level cells should be 50% of the page width.

Currently the nested table is constrained to the widest point of first column and no matter what I do, I can't seem to get around this.

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/afisher988/pen/KZPLLq

Comment: Not all browsers have supported nested tables in the past. this could be different now but I strongly recommend testing any answer given in all major browser environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `colspan` to the `td`:

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

td {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.altRow table {
  width: 100%;
}

/* remove the padding for full width */
.altRow > td {
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="altRow">
      <td colspan="5">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Col 1 50%</td>
              <td>Col 2 50%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Col 1 50%</td>
              <td>Col 2 50%</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```